# Parameter '?user_email' not found in the collection

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, prepared-statement

I am using MySql 5.6x with Visual Studio 2015, windows 10, 64-bit. C# as programming language. In my CRUD.cs (Class file) i have created the following method:

```
public bool dbQuery(string sql,string[] paramList= null)
{
    bool flag = false;
    try
    {
        connect();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,con);
        cmd.Prepare();
        if(paramList != null){ 
         foreach(string i in paramList){
                string[] valus = i.Split(',');
                string p = valus[0];
                string v = valus[1];
                cmd.Parameters[p].Value = v;
            }
         }
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        error(exc);
    }
   }
```

I am passing the query and Parameters List like this:

```
  protected void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM dept_login WHERE (user_email = ?user_email OR user_cell = ?user_cell) AND userkey = ?userkey";
    string[] param = new string[] {
         "?user_email,"+ userid.Text.ToString(),
         "?user_cell,"+ userid.Text.ToString(),
         "?userkey,"+ userkey.Text.ToString()
    };
    if (db.dbQuery(sql, param))
    {
        msg.Text = "Ok";
    }
    else
    {
        msg.Text = "<strong class='text-danger'>Authentication Failed</strong>";
    }
  }
```

Now the problem is that after the loop iteration complete, it directly jumps to the catch() Block and generate an Exception that:

```
Parameter '?user_email' not found in the collection.
```

Am i doing this correct to send params like that? is there any other way to do the same?
Thanks

EDIT: I think the best way might be the two-dimensional array to collect the parameters and their values and loop then within the method to fetch the parameters in cmd.AddWidthValues()? I may be wrong...

Comment: You know that `?user_email` and `?user_cell` both get the value from `userid.Text.ToString()`?

Comment: Yes, user id might be user_email or user_cell number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **dbQuery** you don't create the parameters collection with the expected names, so you get the error when you try to set a value for a parameter that doesn't exist

```
public bool dbQuery(string sql,string[] paramList= null)
{
    bool flag = false;
    try
    {
        connect();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,con);
        cmd.Prepare();
        if(paramList != null){ 
            foreach(string i in paramList){
                string[] valus = i.Split(',');
                string p = valus[0];
                string v = valus[1];
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p, v);
            }
        }
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
           flag = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        error(exc);
    }
}
```

Of course this will add every parameter with a datatype equals to a string and thus is very prone to errors if your datatable columns are not of string type

A better approach would be this one

```
List<MySqlParameter> parameters = new List<MySqlParameter>()
{
   {new MySqlParameter() 
        { 
           ParameterName = "?user_mail", 
           MySqlDbType= MySqlDbType.VarChar,
           Value = userid.Text
         },
   {new MySqlParameter() 
        { 
           ParameterName = "?user_cell", 
           MySqlDbType= MySqlDbType.VarChar,
           Value = userid.Text
         },

   {new MySqlParameter() 
        { 
           ParameterName = "?userkey", 
           MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar,
           Value = userkey.Text
         },

}
if (db.dbQuery(sql, parameters))
 ....
```

and in **dbQuery** receive the list adding it to the parameters collection

```
public bool dbQuery(string sql, List<MySqlParameter> paramList= null)
{
    bool flag = false;
    try
    {
        connect();
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql,con);
        cmd.Prepare();
        if(paramList != null)
         cmd.Parameters.AddRange(paramList.ToArray());

        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        error(exc);
    }
}
```

By the way, unrelated to your actual problem, but your code doesn't seem to close and dispose the connection. This will lead to very nasty problems to diagnose and fix. Try to use the using statement and avoid a global connection variable

**EDIT**
As you have noticed the ExecuteNonQuery doesn't work with a SELECT statement, you need to use ExecuteReader and check if you get some return value

```
    using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        flag = reader.HasRows;
    }
```

This, of course, means that you will get troubles when you want to insert, update or delete record where instead you need the ExecuteNonQuery. Creating a general purpose function to handle different kind of query is very difficult and doesn't worth the work and debug required. Better use some kind of well know ORM software like EntityFramework or Dapper.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. @Steve. Also i just tested the line you changed cmd.Paremters.AddWithValue(p,v). I provided the correct user id and password but still if(cmd.ExectureNonQuery() > 0) returns false?

Comment: You are calling a SELECT query. ExecuteNonQuery is to be used for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE, If you want to get back data you need to use ExecuteReader or fill a datatable through an DataAdapter.

Comment: Thank you very much @Steve, i really appreciate your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Commands' Parameters collection does not contain those parameters, so you cannot index them in this manner:
    `cmd.Parameters[p].Value = v;`
You need to add them to the Commands' Parameters collection in this manner: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(p, v);`.